# Javascript / Electron / SQLITE: Iterate over all columns of row

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

by now I'm iterating over all rows like this:

```
let query = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM CARS");    
let cars = [];

while(query.step()) {
    var row = query.getAsObject();                 
    let a = new Car();
    a.color = row.COLOR;
    cars.push(a)        
}
```

How can I loop over all columns like this:

```
foreach(column in row.Columns){
    console.log(column.Name)
    console.log(column.Value)
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getAsObject()` returns an object with key and value fields, you can use the `Object.keys()` function to get an array of keys in your row, and then you can iterate over these keys using `forEach` like so:

```
var row = query.getAsObject();

Object.keys(row).forEach(function(column) {

    console.log(column); // Column Name
    console.log(row[column]); // Column Value
});
```